# Result of array.length underfined but in console there are elements in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an object:

```
var Points={
    cost:[],
    amount:[],
    risk:[]
};
```

Also have some array with elements `ar=[several elements]`.
Then I pushing elements in this arrays:

```
for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
   if() Points.amount.push(some_element);
   else if() Points.cost.push(some_element);
   else if() Points.risk.push(some_element);         
}
```

But when I am trying to get length of, for example, `console.log(Points.cost.length)` I get `0`. Moreover, when I result of `console.log(Points)` will be: [image]

Array(0)???
But if I open this Object in console, I see [image]

Result of `console.log(Points.cost[0])` will be `undefined`. Why is that so??

P.S. Using Angularjs, but I don't think that it is matter and has any influence on my problem.

Comment: can you replicate in a fiddle

Comment: Not reproducible with the code snippets as shown. My guess(!) would be that you are perhaps performing something asynchronous here, and are not handling that correctly.

Comment: looks like a standard asynchronous execution resulting in a race condition. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(Points))` and this will most likely be `undefined` as well

Comment: console.log gives reference to object. you are printing when only object is initialized i guess, not after the update of object.

Comment: @Durga, Thanks!!! You are right!!